# How to get contact info?

Tags: android, uri, android-contacts

so I'm good with getting contacts.  I assign the contacts to a list view and am able to see them.  When I click a contact, it launches a new activity which for right now, I just want to display that contact's ID.  So what I do is set the contact ID to "set_id", and when you click a contact, it calls "get_id", assigns the ID to contactId, and passes that into a putextra...

> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.content.CursorLoader;
>   import android.content.Intent; import android.database.Cursor; import
>   android.net.Uri; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.provider.ContactsContract; import android.view.Menu; import
>   android.view.View; import android.widget.AdapterView; import
>   android.widget.ListView;
>
> public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> ListItemDetails Detail;
>
> ListView mListView;
> ArrayList<ListItemDetails> details;
> Uri contacts;
> String contactName;
> int contactPic;
> int contactId;
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>     mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
>     details = new ArrayList<ListItemDetails>();
>
>     contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
>     CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
>             this, contacts, null, null, null, null);
>     Cursor c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
>
>     while (c.moveToNext()) {
>         contactId = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
>         contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
>
>         Detail = new ListItemDetails();
>         Detail.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
>         Detail.setName(contactName);
>         Detail.set_id(contactId);
>         details.add(Detail);
>
>     }
>     c.close();
>
>     mListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(details, this));
>     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
>
>             Intent i = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ContactDetails.class);
>             i.putExtra("contactId", contactId);
>             startActivity(i);
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

now, in the new Activity, I just want it to display the contact ID for now (still learning).  So I call Bundle getInt, assign the int value to "contactId" and display that on the screen...  and no matter what contact I select, I shows that the id = 0.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's the second activity:

> import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class ContactDetails extends Activity {
>
> ```
> int contactId;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.contactinfo);
>
>     Bundle extras = new Bundle();
>     contactId = extras.getInt("contactId");
>
>     TextView contactName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactName);
>
>     contactName.setText("You clicked " + contactId);
> } }
> ```

tl;dr   no matter what contact I pick in my listview, it's saying the contact ID = 0, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
```

when you do this you create a new Bundle named extras and not the extras that you added to the activivty.

instead try:

```
contactId = getIntent().getIntExtra("contactId",0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I won't be able to try until tonight, but if it works, I'll make sure to check your answer.  thanks again!

Comment: I was able to test it now... and now when I click on a contact, no matter which one (I have 5 in my emulator), it says I clicked ID # 8

Comment: yes,
        contactId = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
you are reading into contactId the ColumnIndex and not the Id

Comment: Ok, I've spent the last hour with your last comment and I can't find a good solution. I find a hundred different ways to get contact info.  Forgetting my code for a second, could you point me to where you think the most efficient way to do this is?

Comment: forget my last question.  Have a friend helping me out.  Thanks for all of your help